# Update spinner items based on the selected item of another spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to update a spinner by a selected item from another spinner. The following code block describes how I did it.

I could successfully update the *spinner3* using the if statement inside onItemSelected() method. But my problem is that it seems that a loop just keeps running which automatically selects value "5" from *spinner2* (so the Toast just keeps spitting out "You've chosen 5").

When the activity is loaded, the Toast will display each selection from all three spinners. Does it mean that the first selection for each spinner is done when an adapter is set to a spinner?

And does binding adapter3 to spinner3 (in the if statement) trigger a new selection of spinner2?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class WheelchairHelperMain extends Activity{

Spinner spinner2;
Spinner spinner3;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wheelchair_helper_main);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.destinations_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.departure_timeH_list,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());



}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //use the selected station and departure time to calculate the required time
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"You've chosen： " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos), 2);
            toast.show();

            if (spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("5")){
                adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(WheelchairHelperMain.this,R.array.departure_timeH5M_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

            Log.v("spinner2","5");
            }else if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("6")){

                adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(WheelchairHelperMain.this,R.array.departure_timeH6M_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

                Log.v("spinner2","6");
            }

    }



    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
}
```

The following are the xml files.
This is the string-array for spinner2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="departure_timeH_prompt">何時？</string>
<string-array name="departure_timeH_list">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>  7   </item>
    <item>  8   </item>
    <item>  9   </item>
    <item>  10  </item>
    <item>  11  </item>
    <item>  12  </item>
    <item>  13  </item>
    <item>  14  </item>
    <item>  15  </item>
    <item>  16  </item>
    <item>  17  </item>
    <item>  18  </item>
    <item>  19  </item>
    <item>  20  </item>
    <item>  21  </item>
    <item>  22  </item>
    <item>  23  </item>
    <item>  24  </item>
    <item>  0   </item>       
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The string-array for spinner3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="departure_timeM_prompt">何分？</string>
 <string-array name="departure_timeH5M_list">
    <item>  5   </item>
    <item>  24  </item>
    <item>  38  </item>
    <item>  52  </item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="departure_timeH6M_list">
    <item>  01  </item>
    <item>  08  </item>
    <item>  17  </item>
    <item>  25  </item>
    <item>  34  </item>
    <item>  41  </item>
    <item>  47  </item>
    <item>  57  </item>
 </string-array>
</resources>
```

I just found my problems.

In the original code:

```
  spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

is called inside the `onItemSelectedListener`. When an adapter is set to an `AdapterView`, the first item on the adapter will be automatically chosen once. So, it will trigger the listener again.

And since I didn't set a flag to distinguish whether the selection comes from spinner2 and put the `spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3)`, it will just keep running the "choosing first item on adapter3 -> check if the selected item is 5" loop.

So, inserting the following flag in the original code works for me:

```
if (parent.getId()==2131165201){
  //code to check selected item and define new adapter3 for spinner3
```

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest u use the position returned by the onItemclickListener and use it in an array initializing array adapter for that spinner: like---

`

```
String hrs[]=getStringArray(R.array.departure_timeH6M_list);
  if(hrs[pos].equals("5"))
    { 

    }
```

`

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

When the Spinner change put the data Inside the adapter of the next spinner . And the just write `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` The content Inside the next spinner will change.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on to how achieve that? I've tried this by first binding the new string-array (xml file) to the adapter, and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). But nothing happened. Does changing the data need to be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly spinner is selecting a value by default.Yes that is correct if spinner sets to an adapter it will selects to first value. you have to write simple hack in onItemselectedListener to clear that default selection.
take one int variable=-1
in my code it is ageposition
im taking one boolean value age selected to find the default selection.
if(ageselected) means spinner selected by user.

finally use ageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

```
 class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
            if(ageposition==-1)
            {
                ageselected=false;
                ageposition=pos;
            }
            else
            {
                ageposition=pos;
                ageselected=true;
                childage=age[pos];
            }


        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Dummy
        }
    }
```

Hope the above code helps you

Comment: I don't understand where does the value of `ageposition` come from. Would you please elaborate more? I think it might be useful to deselect the default selection if there is any way to do it.

Comment: see for spinner without selecting any value also the default value will be selected this value will be first item in the array which will be used in arrayadapter.If we use setAdapter it will calls onitemselected which will sets the position value is "0".so for this small hack is that im taking a int variable ageposition initally it will be '-1'.If this variable is '-1' means by default it is calling Onitemselected using setAdapter.Using this condition we are finding whether user explicitly selecting spinner or that is due to setAdapter.If that is not -1 user is selecting spinner.